# Combine 'toc' and 'hide input' when using nbconvert html export

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, nbconvert

I would like to export my Jupyter notebook to html displaying the table of contents (toc2) AND hiding the input cells at the same time in the export.

I use a template to hide the code (https://github.com/ihuston/jupyter-hide-code-html), which works fine for itself.

For displaying the table of contents I run the command `jupyter nbconvert --to html_toc FILE.ipynb`, which works as well.

As soon as I try to combine both by `jupyter nbconvert --to html_toc --template HIDE_CELL FILE.ipynb`, only cells are hidden, but the toc is not shown anymore. Has anyone found a solution to combine both functions?

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 5):

I tried this command below and it hides the code and generates table of contents:

`jupyter nbconvert /path/filename --to=html_toc --TemplateExporter.exclude_input=True`

The above worked for: Ubuntu 18.10 and jupyter lab.

Comment: Thanks. This works but images are saved in a separate directory along with the html. Is there a way to embed the images within the exported html. So, html -> with toc, no code and embedded images.

Comment: This has to have toc2 or toc3 nbextensions installed, it does not work with jupyter basic toc or the jupyterlab toc extension.