# How to embed images in html using nbconvert export with 'toc' and 'hide input'?

Tags: html, jupyter-notebook, python-3.7, tableofcontents, nbconvert

My question is an extension of this one ([Combine 'toc' and 'hide input' when using nbconvert html export](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49926287/combine-toc-and-hide-input-when-using-nbconvert-html-export)). The suggested solution works on Win 10 (Anaconda, Jupyter notebook) but the images are saved in a separate directory.

I would like to embed the images in the html so I can share it on its own. How can I do this?